# When purging old kernels should I also purge `linux-image-extra`?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, purge

I've read some questions on here about purging old kernels to make room in `/boot`. The recommendation is to run something like this: `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x-{xx,xx,xx}-generic` but there is no mention of `linux-image-extra-x.x.x-xx-generic`.

Should I be purging these as well?

For example here is my current output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`:

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic                         3.13.0-55.94                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic                         3.13.0-57.95                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic                   3.13.0-44.73                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic                   3.13.0-45.74                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic                   3.13.0-55.94                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic                   3.13.0-57.95                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.57.64                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of `linux-image-extra` without `linux-image` of the same version. You can purge them.

Comment: There is no mention of `linux-image-extra` in this 1000 vote+ Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu But they do mention `linux-headers` 29 times which your short answer is missing. Is there a link which tells us everything to remove?